# Figure number and caption on two lines

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I want to make the Figure number on one line followed by the caption on the second line. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
Example

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\usepackage[labelsep=newline]{caption}`.

Comment: @Zarko, it works but Figure number and the caption are not centered under the image.

Comment: see my answer below. they are centered. for other caption formatting see documentation for the package `caption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let me convert my comment to an answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[labelsep=newline]{caption} % <---
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
Example

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure with math expression: $2+2=4$}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

in case, that you like to have centered text in caption, add option `justification=centering` to `caption`:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=newline,justification=centering]{caption}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm exactly at the situation as in Figure 1, what I want to get is as in Figure 2.

Comment: @Fib1123, sorry, your comment is not clear. do you like to have centered text in caption even if it is longer than one line?

Comment: yes. I know without mathmode within the caption it can be achieved by putting //. But when I do that within mathmode, this error shows "Argument of \@tempf has an extra }", even though I don't have an extra "}"

Answer (score 1):

You can load the package `caption`and do the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
Example

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{\\first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{\\second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

With math mode and math expressions,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelsep=newline]{caption}

\begin{document}
Example

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{$\Pi \succ \Lambda$}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{$\Phi \prec \Lambda$}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I hope it helps.

Romain

Comment: It's still not working. I had \usepackage{caption} in my original code, forgot to put it in the mwe. Just edited.
My caption has mathsymbols on it. When I do what you've suggested, it shows this error. Argument of \@tempf has an extra }.

Comment: What math symbols do you have?

Comment: By math symbols, I meant mathmode within caption.

Comment: It should work the same way, although you might need to use some packages like amsmath or similar